# MySQL com_select?

Tags: mysql, cache, tuning

I'm looking to tune my query cache a bit. According to [7.6.3.4. Query Cache Status and Maintenance](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-status-and-maintenance.html) in the manual:

> The Com_select value is given by this formula: Qcache_inserts
>   + Qcache_not_cached
>   + queries with errors found during the column-privileges check

However in [5.1.5. Server Status Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Com_xxx) it suggests that this is maintained by the DBMS. Having said that

```
mysql> show status like 'Com_select%';
```

Always returns a value of 1 - and I'm pretty sure I've run more than one non-cached select query on my database since it started.

It looks as if [other people are similarly confused](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3808841/Optimizing-the-MySQL-Query-Cache.htm).

Is this status variable redundant? Which bit of the manual is wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command

```
show status like 'Com_select%';
```

is at the session level. You probably want the server level.

Try

```
show global status like 'Com_select';
```

Comment: Thanks Rolando - that explains why I was getting a value of 1, but the value I do get is approx 10 times Qcache_inserts + Qcache_not_cached (and I don't think 90% of my queries are failing)